# firebase/flutter app - user still logged in even after sign in provider remove access

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-signin, apple-sign-in

I can succesfully log in my flutter app using Google/Apple sign in and I can see the logged users in my firebase console.

When I try to go to my google/apple account and from settings remove my app from those with sign in capabilities, I'm expecting the next time I start my emulator and try open my app to be logged out and asked to log in again, but I'm still logged in.

(for reference:
Google

- Open your Google Account.
- Choose Security.
- Scroll down to "Signing in to other sites" and choose Signing in with Google.
- Choose the app or service you want to remove and then Remove Access.

Apple

- go to Settings, then tap your name.
- Tap Password & Security > Apps Using Apple ID.
- Select the app or developer, then tap Stop Using Apple ID. )

I've read that firebase automatically refreshes tokens about every hour, but even after that time I can open the app and still be logged in.

I couldn't find any documentation on this case, is this the expected behavior? if not, what could be the problem?

Thanks.

The tests has been done on an iOS 13 emulator.

for sign in with apple I used the package "the_apple_sign_in"
for Google's sign in the "google_sign_in" as described by firebase's tutorial ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth?hl=en )

Comment: Please check the duplicate answers to how you can solve that using a list of banned users.